# Why I am getting 500 error all routes with empty response after deploying .NET core project to IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, navision

I have developed a .NET WebAPI project that works with NAV soap service using connected services. Every thing is fine in my visual studio but after I publish project to folder and transfer it to remote server and serving it on IIS Manager, I get 500 internal server error on all endpoints with empty response.
I have checked even log file but output is like this (without any details):

```
 2021-11-04 08:52:34 172.17.19.126 POST /api/Auth/Login - #port - #ip Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/95.0.4638.54+Safari/537
```

This is my first .NET project deployment, sorry if my question was so basic.

Comment: 500 means Internal Server Error which means unhandled exception so you're missing some logs there. If you can access the server, run the app manually on the console and check how it behaves or check that you aren't ignoring exceptions

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.